# capturing full URL of a GET request in AngularJS including query params

Tags: angularjs, restangular, cachefactory

I'm using http interceptor. I do see all the values when I make a Restangular GET request. Here is the code for my request interceptor.

```
request: function (config) {
    // see link below to see value of config
    console.log('config', config);

    // below returns full url except query string
    console.log('location', $location.absUrl());

    // $rootScope.cacheData is $cacheFactory
    console.log('$rootScope', $rootScope.cacheData);

    // only returns {id: "http", size: 3}
    console.log('cache info', $rootScope.cacheData.info());

    // below returns undefined
    console.log('cache get', $rootScope.cacheData.get('http'));

    // other codes removed since it's not related
    // ........
    // ........
    // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
    return config || $q.when(config);
},
```

config value : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlY75.png

Unfortunately, preparing the params captured manually is not 100% guaranteed that it will match what has been cached. I noticed that cacheFactory checks the exact string that was requested. So if our GET request's query parameters are age=12&name=scott then on our http interceptor, we prepare it the other way by putting name first then age(name=scott&age=12), cacheFactory won't find it.

So I'm trying to look for an angular service or factory that will return the full URL equal to the request we made. I tried $location but it's not giving the full GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to parse the config and build it from scratch. It's working great :)

```
if ( config.method == 'GET' && (config.url.indexOf('v1/repeters') != -1) ) {
    // Prepare the full path
    var cachedUrlsLocalStorage;
    var absolutePath = '';
    _(config.params).keys().sort().each( function(key, index) {
        var value = config.params[key];
        absolutePath = absolutePath + key + '=' + value + (index < _(config.params).keys().value().length - 1 ? '&' : '');
    });

    cachedUrlsLocalStorage = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cachedUrls'));
    if (cachedUrlsLocalStorage) {
        var exists = _.findIndex(cachedUrlsLocalStorage, function(cachedData) {
            return cachedData.url == config.url + '?' + absolutePath;
        });
        if (!exists) {
            cachedUrlsLocalStorage.push({url : config.url + '?' + absolutePath, timeExecuted : moment(), expiryTime : moment().add(10, 'minutes')});
            window.localStorage.setItem('cachedUrls', JSON.stringify( cachedUrlsLocalStorage ));
        }
    } else {
        cachedUrlsLocalStorage = [];
        cachedUrlsLocalStorage.push({url : config.url + '?' + absolutePath, timeExecuted : moment(), expiryTime : moment().add(10, 'minutes')});
        window.localStorage.setItem('cachedUrls', JSON.stringify( cachedUrlsLocalStorage ));
    }
}
```